# what's the difference of these two codes?

Tags: javascript

code 1

```
function change_value(){
        var repaet=setInterval(frame,10);
        var width=0;
        function frame(){
            if(width>=200){
                ClearInterval(repeat);
            }
            else{
                width++;
                $('.value').width(width);
            }
        }
    }
```

code 2

```
var repaet=setInterval(frame,10);
function change_value(){        
        var width=0;
        function frame(){
            if(width>=200){
                ClearInterval(repeat);
            }
            else{
                width++;
                $('.value').width(width);
            }
        }
    }
```

the first one is working but the second one is not..
what's the problem of second code?
and how can I make the second code work?

https://jsfiddle.net/5ozr1L2h/1/

Comment: `repaet` vs `repeat` -- is this a typo?

Comment: There's many problems with this code. You should fix those first, then clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, `frame` is declared inside the `change_value` function. It exists only inside that function. Trying to use it outside of that function causes the a *ReferenceError* exception to be thrown.